# Docker-compose mysql: import .sql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

My docker-compose script successfully manages to run a mysql/mariadb service, and copies my "init.sql" script containing the database schema to "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d". However, the sql script is never executed like it should [according to the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/).

There is no error, nothing in the logs. I checked that the sql file is copied at the right place in the container. I checked that the script runs with no errors on an empty database.

What am I missing? Is it even visible in the logs if the script was executed (and for some reason did nothing)?

(**Edit:** docker-compose version: 1.8.1, image mariadb:10.1.21)

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
volumes:
  data-volume: {}
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users_db
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./resources/docker-sql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  backend:
    image: myapp
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
```

Comment: According to the source of the [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/b558f64b736650b94df9a90e68ff9e3bc03d4bdb/10.1/docker-entrypoint.sh) (the script which is supposed to execute your `init.sql`) there should be line in the logs if it is executed (line 154). Could you add the output of `docker logs`? Furthermore, your script will only be executed the first time the container is started (line 76)! You have to delete it between tries.

Comment: Oh, I had to delete the container indeed. Thanks! `docker-compose stop`, `docker-compose rm`, `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Whould any of you to write an official answer? :)

Comment: Note that there are no logs printed relative to the sql script actually being run, though. Maybe there is a verbose option. But not a problem anymore. If @fzgregor doesn't write an answer of it I'll do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the source of the [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/b558f64b736650b94df9a90e68ff9e3bc03d4bdb/10.1/docker-entrypoint.sh) file of the mariadb image, the script which is supposed to execute your `init.sql`, it becomes clear that

1. the script will only be executed when the container didn't contain a database before (line 76 of the script), and
2. there will a log output informing you that you script was called.

**To achieve this with `docker-compose` you have to stop the service, remove the container (to get rid of the database) and start it again:**

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm
docker-compose start
```

Here is an example of the image's behavior, only with a `.sh` file instead of `.sql`:

```
$ cat hello.sh 
echo "This is output of the hello script"
$ docker run -it -v `pwd`/hello.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/hello.sh -v mariadb_test:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 mariadb   
Initializing database
2017-02-09 14:13:54 140617005938624 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 63 ...
2017-02-09 14:13:54 140617005938624 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-02-09 14:13:54 140617005938624 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-02-09 14:13:54 140617005938624 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
[...]
2017-02-09 14:14:03 139836212086528 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-02-09 14:14:03 139836971521984 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-02-09 14:14:03 139836971521984 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@830dbd0908f3' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-02-09 14:14:03 139836971521984 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@830dbd0908f3' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-02-09 14:14:03 139836971521984 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.21-MariaDB-1~jessie'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: dau6voh4eej2jooRohpiop4eh6ahl7Uz
2017-02-09 14:14:05 139836970654464 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@830dbd0908f3' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/hello.sh
This is output of the hello script

2017-02-09 14:14:05 139836970351360 [Note] mysqld: Normal shutdown

2017-02-09 14:14:05 139836970351360 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-02-09 14:14:05 139836195301120 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-02-09 14:14:05 139836970351360 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-02-09 14:14:05 139836970351360 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2017-02-09 14:14:07 139836970351360 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1616829
2017-02-09 14:14:07 139836970351360 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete


MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
[...]
```

You see somewhere in the log output the call and its stdout of the `hello.sh` script is buried. On subsequent starts of the container the script is not executed because the database is already created (in the local mariadb volume):

```
$ docker run -it -v `pwd`/hello.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/hello.sh -v mariadb_test:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 mariadb
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 1 ...
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1616839
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140154429736704 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@830dbd0908f3' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-02-09 14:19:13 140155189532608 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.21-MariaDB-1~jessie'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Comment: Anyone else with an issue the commands `docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm` are very key as they help you start over . Otherwise your changes to the compose file might not be effected.

Comment: @GideonMaina You're missing the && sign. `docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm`. I used `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` worked for me.

Comment: `docker-compose down -v` does this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late, but I have found another more accurate solution.

Through `depends_on` and `healthcheck`, don't run backend until mysql dump has finished. The only detail is that you must run it with version 2.1.

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '2.1'
volumes:
  data-volume: {}
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users_db
    depends_on:
      backend:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./resources/docker-sql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  backend:
    image: myapp
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=you_pass --database=your_db --execute \"SELECT * FROM last_table_of_your_dump;\""
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 10
```